# Assistance required with angular label of a border matrix in latex

Tags: latex

Can anyone help me with the latex code where i can make the labels of a bordermatrix angular?

**The current code:**

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, BCOR=10mm, english]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[counterclockwise]{rotating}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\bbordermatrix\bordermatrix
\patchcmd{\bbordermatrix}{8.75}{4.75}{}{}
\patchcmd{\bbordermatrix}{\left(}{\left[}{}{}
\patchcmd{\bbordermatrix}{\right)}{\right]}{}{}

\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\protected\def\fpset#1#2{\edef#1{\fpeval{#2}}}

\begin{document}
    \fpset\RAngle{-45}
    \begin{center}
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
            $\bbordermatrix{ & \rotatebox{\RAngle}{$m_{2}E_{1}$} & \rotatebox{\RAngle}{$m_{2}E_{2}$} & \rotatebox{\RAngle}{$m_{2}E_{3}$} & \rotatebox{\RAngle}{$m_{2}E_{4}$} & \rotatebox{\RAngle}{$m_{2}E_{5}$} & \rotatebox{\RAngle}{$m_{2}E_{1}\cap m_{2}E_{2}\cap m_{2}E_{3}\cap m_{2}E_{4}\cap m_{2}E_{5}$} \cr            
                \rotatebox{\RAngle}{$m_{1}E_{1}$} & \colorbox{Green!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Green!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01}  \cr          
                \rotatebox{\RAngle}{$m_{1}E_{2}$} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Yellow!50}{0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Yellow!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01}  \cr         
                \rotatebox{\RAngle}{$m_{1}E_{3}$} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Aquamarine!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Aquamarine!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01}  \cr            
                \rotatebox{\RAngle}{$m_{1}E_{4}$} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Orange!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Orange!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01}  \cr            
                \rotatebox{\RAngle}{$m_{1}E_{5}$} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Magenta!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Magenta!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01}  \cr          
                \rotatebox{\RAngle}{$m_{1}E_{1}\cap m_{1}E_{2}\cap m_{1}E_{3}\cap m_{1}E_{4}\cap m_{1}E_{5}$} & \colorbox{Green!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Yellow!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Aquamarine!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Orange!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Magenta!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{MidnightBlue!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01}  \cr
            }$
        }
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

**This results to a the following:**
[image: This results to a the following:]

**I want the matrix to look something like this which i did in photoshop:**
[image: I want the matrix to look something like this which i did in photoshop:]

Comment: Please don't juts throw code fragments at us. Make a [mre] instead

Comment: I am so sorry. i forgot to make the code clean and workable. I was  in a hurry and totally forgot about that. I have updated the code which is standalone and and shortened with the required packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of dirty hacks:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, BCOR=10mm, english]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[counterclockwise]{rotating}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\let\bbordermatrix\bordermatrix
\patchcmd{\bbordermatrix}{8.75}{4.75}{}{}
\patchcmd{\bbordermatrix}{\left(}{\left[}{}{}
\patchcmd{\bbordermatrix}{\right)}{\right]}{}{}

\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
\protected\def\fpset#1#2{\edef#1{\fpeval{#2}}}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
%\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \fpset\RAngle{-45}
    \begin{center}
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
        $ \begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
             & \smash{\rotatebox[origin = cl]{\RAngle}{$m_{2}E_{1}$}} & \smash{\rotatebox[origin = cl]{\RAngle}{$m_{2}E_{2}$}} & \smash{\rotatebox[origin = cl]{\RAngle}{$m_{2}E_{3}$}} & \smash{\rotatebox[origin = cl]{\RAngle}{$m_{2}E_{4}$}} & \smash{\rotatebox[origin = cl]{\RAngle}{$m_{2}E_{5}$}} & {\makebox[0pt]{\hspace{11em}\rotatebox[origin = cl]{\RAngle}{$m_{2}E_{1}\cap m_{2}E_{2}\cap m_{2}E_{3}\cap m_{2}E_{4}\cap m_{2}E_{5}$}}} \cr            
                \smash{\rotatebox[origin = cr]{\RAngle}{$m_{1}E_{1}$}} & \colorbox{Green!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Green!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01}  \cr          
                \smash{\rotatebox[origin = cr]{\RAngle}{$m_{1}E_{2}$}} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Yellow!50}{0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Yellow!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01}  \cr         
                \smash{\rotatebox[origin = cr]{\RAngle}{$m_{1}E_{3}$}} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Aquamarine!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Aquamarine!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01}  \cr            
                \smash{\rotatebox[origin = cr]{\RAngle}{$m_{1}E_{4}$}} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Orange!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Orange!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01}  \cr            
                \smash{\rotatebox[origin = cr]{\RAngle}{$m_{1}E_{5}$}} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Gray!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Magenta!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Magenta!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01}  \cr          
                \smash{ \rotatebox[origin = cr]{\RAngle}{$m_{1}E_{1}\cap m_{1}E_{2}\cap m_{1}E_{3}\cap m_{1}E_{4}\cap m_{1}E_{5}$} }& \colorbox{Green!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Yellow!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Aquamarine!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Orange!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{Magenta!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01} & \colorbox{MidnightBlue!50}{(0.01*0.01) = 0.01}  \cr
            \end{pNiceMatrix}$
        }
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. could you please guide me the command which can extend the bracket sizes a bit bigger so that it goes 0.5cm over the top/bottom row? i will be using the bNiceMatrix instead of pNiceMatrix.

Comment: @TahasanulIbrahim Shall the labels in the first row then be partially withing the brackets or should they be moved further to the top?

Comment: i say the current position is okey. its just the the bracket size does not cove the full height of the colored columns.. if the bracket is a bit longer i think that will do...

Comment: @TahasanulIbrahim As a quick hack you could place `\rule{0pt}{0.7cm}` before the first colour box and `\rule[-0.5cm]{0pt}{0.7cm}` after the last one

Comment: @TahasanulIbrahim For a clean solution let the nicematric package colour your cells and check out the `extra-margin` option